# 起動時エラーが起きる LoadError: libffi.so.7: cannot open shared object file

Tags: ruby-on-rails

私はGemfileをいろいろ変えてテストする事があるのですが、その時はGemfile.lockを削除して vendor/bundle 以下のサブディレクトリーをすべて削除して 再度 `bundle install` します。そして今まではそれで問題ありませんでした。

でも最近pumaでアプリをスタートさせると次のエラーが出ます。これはそのうちバージョンアップ等で解決することでしょうか？それとも vendor/bundle 以下は削除してはいけないという事でしょうか？あるいは他に何か原因があるのでしょうか？

Ruby 3.0.0
Rails 6.1.3
Ubuntu 18.04

```
! Unable to load application: LoadError: libffi.so.7: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory - /home/xxxxx/rails-data/jquery1_samp/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/ffi-1.15.0/lib/ffi_c.so
bundler: failed to load command: puma (/home/xxxxx/rails-data/jquery1_samp/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/bin/puma)
/home/xxxxx/rails-data/jquery1_samp/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require': libffi.so.7: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory - /home/xxxxx/rails-data/jquery1_samp/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/ffi-1.15.0/lib/ffi_c.so (LoadError)
        from /home/xxxxx/rails-data/jquery1_samp/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
        from /home/xxxxx/rails-data/jquery1_samp/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
        from /home/xxxxx/rails-data/jquery1_samp/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
 -1.7.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb....
..
..
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ruby, rails, bundler のバージョンをそれぞれ如何に変えても
railsの機能すべてが全くダメになっていたのですが、
`Ubuntuを 18.04から 20.04へアップグレード`
する事によって解決出来ました。内容的には理解できていません。
ffi が何か変わった様に思えます。